# Compiler warning (c++11): Zero as null pointer constant

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, c++11, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using QTCreator with ROS Plugin and compilie my nodes with C++11 support. I get the following compiler warning when using e.g. ROS_DEBUG(). How can setup QTCreator to ignore this warning?

```
Warning: zero as null pointer constant
expanded from macro 'ROS_DEBUG'
expanded from macro 'ROS_LOG'
expanded from macro 'ROS_LOG_COND'
expanded from macro 'ROSCONSOLE_DEFINE_LOCATION'
```

In CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324627/compiler-warning-(c++11):-zero-as-null-pointer-constant/) by [alex_](https://answers.ros.org/users/34815/alex_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2019-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related: [ros-industrial/ros_qtc_plugin#321](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_qtc_plugin/issues/321).

> How can setup QTCreator to ignore this warning?

I'm not sure whether you can do this globally, but you can suppress it per-file with:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant"
```

That's not very nice though as it now ignores those for everything, not just the macros.

---

It would appear this has already been addressed in [ros/rosconsole#14](https://github.com/ros/rosconsole/pull/14). That has changed everything to use `nullptr` instead of `0`, but that has only been released into Melodic, not Kinetic afaict (part of `1.13.8`, but Kinetic only has `1.12.14`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex_](https://answers.ros.org/users/34815/alex_/) on 2019-06-04**:
Thanks! This makes it easier to focus on important :) warnings.